# Removing extra spacing on top of a table

Tags: html, css, css-float, html-table

I'm creating a layout using div and table.

```
<div class="main-container bg-white">
  <div class="main-content-container bg-blue">
    <div class="logo-container">
      <img src="http://thebrainfever.com/images/apple-logos/Silhouette.png" width="100px" height="100px"/>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-container">
      <a href="#">Menu 1</a> | <a href="#">Menu 2</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="main-container bg-white">
  <div class="main-content-container bg-yellow">
    <table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="wrapper">
      <tr>
        <td style="width: 100%; padding: 0px 5px; background-color: grey;" colspan="2">
          Content
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/odtkrumL/

The layout seems OK except there is extra spacing at the top of the table such that the text "Content" is being pushed down a bit (the yellow spacing). How could I remove the extra (yellow) spacing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a quick fix add **display:block** to your **.wrapper**

```
.wrapper {
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        display: block;
    }
```

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/qr7byupa/

Comment: Hi, if I add `display: table;` the yellow spacing will be removed, but it will become extra spacing at the bottom of the "header part" (the one with logo and menu). I want to keep the layout to be like what I did, but without extra spacing in the content.

Comment: This should solve your issue add display block to your wrapper class .wrapper {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
}

Comment: If I add that style, how to make the table to fill 100% of the column? Adding that style will directly shrink the table to the text length..

Comment: As you have mentioned the table width as 100%, It will occupy the entire column. The element is now a block level element.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
   .bg-white {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    display:flex
    }
```

Comment: Hi, with `display: flex` the header's height will increase. I want to keep the header's height. Thank you.